# Show Table Again Without Reprocessing All PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, email

I am making a form where a user can build a shopping cart and then once they submit it, they are taken to a page that displays their final contents in their cart. Behind the scenes, PHP is sending an email to myself which needs to contain the exact same table that was already rendered on the page once however I do not want to have to rebuild the table again, I would like to use the one that was already built. I don't know how to do this. My code works and everything is how I want it so don't

Below is a sample of code kind of like I have built, I cut out the repeat stuff to make it easier to look at.

```
    <table align="center" width="100%">
    <thead align="center">
    <tr>
    <td style="border-color: #000000; background-color: #000000; color: #ffffff; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;" class="head"><b>Product</b></td>
    <td style="border-color: #000000; background-color: #000000; color: #ffffff; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;" class="head"><b>Item ID</b></td>
    <td style="border-color: #000000; background-color: #000000; color: #ffffff; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;" class="head"><b>Quantity</b></td>
    <td style="border-color: #000000; background-color: #000000; color: #ffffff; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;" class="head"><b>Cost</b></td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    $i = 0;
    $cmf073 = mysqli_result($result, $i, "cmf073");
    $cmf073total = mysqli_result($result, $i, "cmf073total"); 
    if($cmf073 > 0)
    {?>
    <tr>
    <td align="center" style="border-color: #000000; background-color: #ffffff; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;" class="body">
    Printable 3-Up Certified Mail® Form
    </td>
    <td align="center" style="border-color: #000000; background-color: #ffffff; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;" class="body">
    CMF-073
    </td>
    <td align="center" style="border-color: #000000; background-color: #ffffff; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;" class="body">
    <?php echo number_format($cmf073 * 1000, 0) ." Forms";?>
    </td>
    <td align="center" style="border-color: #000000; background-color: #ffffff; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;" class="body">
    $<?php echo number_format($cmf073total, 2);?>
    </td></tr>
    <?php
    }
    echo "<tr border='0'><td></td><td></td><td></td><td align='center'><b>Cost Estimate: ";
    echo "$".number_format($total, 2)."</b><br />
    <font style='font-size: 8px;'>Plus Tax, Shipping and Handling</font></td></tr></tbody></table>";

    }
    $email = "x@y.net";
    $subject = "New Customer Order Request from $company" ;
    $message =  "A new order request has been submitted on y.net</br></br>

    Contact Info:</br>
    $firstName $lastName</br>
    $phone | $email</br>
    $company</br>
    $address1</br>
    $address2</br>
    $city, $state $zip";
    $headers = 'From: x@y.net' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: x@y.net' . "\r\n" .
    'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

So I need the table that was already generated at the top of the code to be placed in the bottom of the email $message. But I don't want to regenerate everything again since PHP has already created the table that I need. Sorry if this is confusing, I don't really know how to explain it. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe make a variable called `$table` and this contains all your rows etc. ie `$table = '<table><tr><td><td></tr><tr><td></td></tr></table>`. Then echo this out on to the page and similarly echo this into the email.

Comment: A template engine, like smarty, can cache you template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the beginning of the table

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>
<table align='.....'
//stuff
//more stuff
```

At the end of the table

```
</table>
<?php
$myTable=ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo $myTable;
?>
```

Now in `$myTable` you have the content of the table, you can use it in your mail.

```
$message.=$myTable;
mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Thanks! Wish I could accept all of the answers, but you get the check for being the most detailed.

Answer (score 4):

You can use output buffering:

`<?php ob_start(); ?>`

`... // your table html exactly as you have it`

`<?php $var = ob_get_clean();`

At this point you can echo `$var` to your page and also include it in a `mail()` call and you avoid having to store it all in a variable by chaining PHP strings together.

Comment: Amazing! Didn't even know this existed myself. +1 for being the first to give this solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can turn on output buffering with [`ob_start`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) before the table, use [`ob_get_contents`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php) to store it in a variable, then end buffering with [`ob_end_flush`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php) to send it to the client.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the <?..?> tags to write straight to the page, store the table contents in a variable:

```
if($cmf073 > 0)
    $table="
    <tr>
    <td align="center" style="border-color: #000000; background-color: #ffffff; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;" class="body">
    Printable 3-Up Certified Mail® Form
    </td>
    <td align="center" style="border-color: #000000; background-color: #ffffff; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;" class="body">
    CMF-073
    </td>
    <td align="center" style="border-color: #000000; background-color: #ffffff; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;" class="body">
    ".number_format($cmf073 * 1000, 0)." Forms
    </td>
    <td align="center" style="border-color: #000000; background-color: #ffffff; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;" class="body">
    \$".number_format($cmf073total, 2)."
    </td></tr>
    ";
}
```

Then you can just say

```
print($table);
```

and when sending the email you can also use the variable again for the email content:

```
$message =  "A new order request has been submitted on y.net</br></br>

$table

Contact Info:</br>
$firstName $lastName</br>
```